# "python" still runs the system version after virtualenv activate

Tags: python, unix, virtualenv

I installed Python 2.7 with these commands:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-unicode=ucs4 --enable-shared LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib"
make && make altinstall
```

Then I created the virtualenv to point to the 2.7 installation:

```
$ virtualenv --python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7 testbox
Already using interpreter /usr/local/bin/python2.7
New python executable in /var/python_venv/testbox/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in /var/python_venv/testbox/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
$ source testbox/bin/activate
(testbox) $ python
Python 2.6.6 ( , Aug 18 2016, 15:13:37)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

But if I activate it its point to 2.6.6:

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
```

EDIT:

I am not sure why this doesn't work, but I can still use the virtualenv in my Apache Django app, so I am not too concerned.

Comment: You could run `which python` in the virtualenv to check it. Looks like you still have the system python running

Comment: $ which python
alias python='/usr/bin/python'
        /usr/bin/python

Comment: Right. Which is not `/usr/local/bin/python2.7`

Comment: You have to edit your `PATH` variable and make sure `/usr/local/bin/` is before `/usr/bin/`

Comment: yes but why is it ignoring  --python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7 ? what else is at play here

Comment: AFAIK, that just uses that python binary to build the virtualenv, your `PATH` variable is what determines the binaries that are ran

Comment: my understanding is by activating it I am explicitly telling it to use the Python binary in the venv. all the tutorials show this without mention of editing the path :/

Comment: Tutorials might not be using RedHat. Not sure. Using `which` seems to point to the correct Python for my virtualenvs.

Comment: `virtualenv` will prepend the correct path. The problem is the alias. Whenever you execute `python`, it will execute whatever is defined in `alias python`. `unalias python` and you will be able to run the correct python version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bottom line:

You have set "`python`" as a shell alias (probably in your shell startup scripts). It interferes with `virtualenv`'s work of replacing what would be run when you type "`python`". Remove the alias, and you're good.

You also don't need to specify `--python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7` 'cuz you're using `virtualenv` from that Python installation, so it already uses it by default.

---

WFM with `virtualenv 1.10.1`: (see a guess further below)

```bash
$ virtualenv --python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7 testbox
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python2.7
New python executable in testbox/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in testbox/bin/python
Installing Setuptools.........................................done.
Installing Pip................................................done.
$ ls -l testbox/bin/
total 40
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2194 Dec  7 03:06 activate
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1250 Dec  7 03:06 activate.csh
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2389 Dec  7 03:06 activate.fish
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1129 Dec  7 03:06 activate_this.py
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  332 Dec  7 03:06 easy_install
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  340 Dec  7 03:06 easy_install-2.7
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  293 Dec  7 03:06 pip
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  301 Dec  7 03:06 pip-2.7
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    9 Dec  7 03:06 python -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    9 Dec  7 03:06 python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 7788 Dec  7 03:06 python2.7
```

And the main thing that `activate` does is:

```bash
PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
```

---

My guess is that you're using `virtualenv` *that was installed for your `/usr/local/bin/python2.7`.* That's the reason for the "Already using..." message. If that's the case, you don't need to pass `--python` because that `virtualenv` is already using it by default (check its shebang).

Still, since `virtualenv` creates a versionless executable and `activate` alters `PATH`, you should get `/var/python_venv/testbox/bin/python` as `python`.

- Since `python` is an alias in your case, and `activate` *doesn't use aliases* - you must have it set in your `bash` startup scripts.

Comment: It works for you because you don't have `python` aliased to the system python. If you add `alias python=/usr/bin/python` in `.bashrc` you will get the same result as the OP when you run `python`.

Comment: @alvits and it shouldn't be - that's what I am driving at.

Comment: My point is that your post is not the solution to the problem. The solution is to get rid of the alias. Django works as claimed because it never used the alias. Only the interactive shell uses the alias.

Comment: @alvits that's my solution, too. But I'm also explaining it.

Comment: How to remove the alias in Kubuntu 17.10. In what script is it?

Comment: @HrvojeT in one of your shell's startup scripts.

Comment: @HrvojeT well, if you didn't type it by hand in the current session, it must be _somewhere_. BTW those are not all the startup scripts that `bash` may use, see its man page. And fyi they can `source` other files. You can always recreate your home dir from `/etc/skel` as a last resort.

Answer (score 21):

You've possibly moved/renamed a folder on the path to the `venv`.

`venv/bin/activate` contains a variable called `VIRTUAL_ENV` (that is used to update the path when activating a `venv`) and this may have a hardcoded reference to the original `venv` location.

```
VIRTUAL_ENV="/Users/<user-name>/<original-path>/venv"
export VIRTUAL_ENV

_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH="$PATH"
PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
```

When you move/rename the folder, the outdated `VIRTUAL_ENV` path is added to your `PATH` when you `activate`. As a result, the first match for `python` will be further down the `PATH` and the first match will most likely be system `python`.

You should update these outdated hardcoded paths within the `venv` folder.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. I was wondering why it stopped working all of a sudden.

Answer (score 4):

If you activated your virtualenv and `which python` gives you `/usr/bin/python` instead of `yourvirtualenv_path/bin/python` you might have a bash alias in your .bashrc or .bash_aliases files as I had.

Steps to fix it:

1. Deactivate virtual environment
2. To check what python is aliased to run: `type python`
3. Find your python alias and delete it from `~/.bash_aliases` or `~/.bashrc`
4. In my case I deleted `alias python='$(which python)' from ~/.bash_aliases`
5. Delete your virtual environment
6. Refresh your .bash files: `source ~/.bashrc` and `source ~/.bash_aliases`
7. Recreate virtualenv
8. Activate virtualenv
9. Run: `which python` should give: `yourvirtualenv_path/bin/python`

Answer (score 1):

If you are on **Windows**, this seemed to work for me.

Check your environment variables and move any Python path declarations in system to user environment variables.