# `which python` after virtualenv activation still shows the non virtualenv path

Tags: python, centos

I have followed the answers in the [question listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41003859/python-still-runs-the-system-version-after-virtualenv-activate) but I still can't get to resolve my problem.

I have a virtual environment for python 2.7 under /var/www/app/env and after activating it, it still shows the same python running as was before I activated the environment. For both the result for `which python` is:

`/usr/bin/python` **but I'd like it to be** `/var/www/app/env/bin/python`

What changes need to be made so that it is like this every time I activate my environment?

**MORE INFO**

This is on `RHEL 4.8` and `Python 2.7.2`. My `.bashrc` file is below:

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

# Uncomment the following line if you don't like systemctl's auto-paging feature
:
# export SYSTEMD_PAGER=

# User specific aliases and functions
source /var/www/app/env/bin/activate
```

There is no other profile file.

With virtual environment activated, `echo $PATH` gives the output:

```
/var/www/app/env/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin
```

With it deactivated, the following is output by `echo $PATH`:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
```

**UPDATE**
I performed the following steps, but there was no change:

Added the following in the `activate` file for the virtual environment:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/var/www/dwm/dwmenv/bin/python"                                 
export OLD_PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH"
```

Added the following to the `deactivate()` function in the same file

```
export PYTHONPATH="$OLD_PYTHONPATH"
```

Deactivated the environment and activated it again, yet no change!

Comment: try to verify you have the python executable in /var/www/app/env/bin

Comment: Is this also the case if you source it manually (not in .bashrc)?

Comment: @Benitok yes it's the same case

Comment: @LiorCohen it's there :(

Comment: After activating, which -a ..., does not find it at all? If not, cd to the bin folder and try to run python from there.

Comment: @LiorCohen it's the same error and I have tried that already

Comment: do you get an error when trying to invoke from the bin folder or you get the wrong python?

Comment: is it possible you have alias named "python"?

Comment: @LiorCohen I get this:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/app/manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management`

Comment: @LiorCohen how do I check if there is an alias named python?

Comment: type in console: alias python

Comment: It says `not found`

Comment: Did you make changes to the `activate` and `deactivate` commands? You're not supposed to do that. Perhaps you have made other changes to system files...?

Comment: @triplee, I only added the one line above in the UPDATE section, but then have reverted it back. No changes made to other sys files

Comment: In the future, use `type python` rather than `which python`; that also knows about aliases, shell functions, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was very basic. The python in the environment's `bin` folder didn't have execute permissions for the owner and group. I added those permissions and now it is able to run properly